# Need a PK or ID for success_message in UpdateView (a class based view)

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I want to send a success message in UpdateView that has a link to allow the user to change his mind about the update. This means I need the primary key.

I haven't been able to determine how to retrieve the primary key in UpdateView. Everything else works, so you'll see in my code, that I have tenatively hard-coded the primary key as 434.

I'm an extreme newb to all of programming, so I'm confident there's stupid stuff in here. I try to reduce my stupid stuff a little at a time. So mostly I want to focus in on how I can retrieve the PK (or ID).  Thanks.

**The URLS:**

```
# CLASS BASED VIEWS #
path('event/list', EventListView.as_view(), name='list'),
path('event/detail/<int:pk>', EventDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('event/create', EventCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
path('event/update/<int:pk>', EventUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
```

**The View:**

```
class EventUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin,UpdateView):

    template_name = 'update.html'
    form_class = EventForm
    success_url = '../list'
    queryset = Event.objects.all()

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):  # here we override the get_object method in UpdateView, don't need queryset
        #obj = Event.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        pk_=self.kwargs.get("pk")
        print("The pk is", pk_)
        return get_object_or_404(Event,pk=pk_)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)

    message_part_1 = "Record has been updated <a href='unupdate?recordtobeunupdated="
    message_part_2 =  '434'
    message_part_3 = "'>Undo</a>"
    undo_message = message_part_1  + message_part_2 + message_part_3
    success_message = (mark_safe(undo_message))
```

**The Model:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Event(models.Model):  # This is our database table
    company = models.CharField(default='UL',   max_length=20)
    engine = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, null=True)  # default the date to today
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='Weights')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    reason = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    assess_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    outcome = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    # the default is True, it can't be blank
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=False)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("SiteEventsAPP: SiteEventsAPP-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    # See below __str__(self) is a special method
    # It does a cool thing
    # Whenever Python asks for a string representation of my Event object, this method returns a human-readable version
    # If there is no string method, then Python returns the object type
    # This class method is really only needed for the admin page

    def __str__(self):
        return self.engine  # I have to have a field here. Whatever field I pick will be the field shown in admin
```

**Here is the outcome the user sees:**[image]

Comment: What are you intending to do with that success_message? It's not a standard attribute of any built-in class-based views.

Comment: Daniel, I added a snippet above to show you. The "undo" is what needs the PK. But if you have a better idea, I'm interested.

Comment: Yes but how are you intending to get that message from the class to the template?

Comment: (Also, it doesn't affect your question, but note that your `get_object` method is unnecessary - it just does what the default implementation would do already. Overriding `get_object` is only necessary when you want to do something unusual. You should remove your version.)

Comment: Okay will do. It was an attempt at retrieving the PK, and a fail.

Comment: The message is already working. That snippet was from a working web app (with the hard coded pk).

Comment: Ah, I missed that you had "SuccessMessageMixin". You need to post the code for that mixin.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the code of the SuccessMessageMixin you will see this:

```
    class SuccessMessageMixin:
    """
    Add a success message on successful form submission.
    """
    success_message = ''

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        success_message = self.get_success_message(form.cleaned_data)
        if success_message:
            messages.success(self.request, success_message)
        return response

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % cleaned_data
```

As you can see here the function that returns the success message is `get_success_message` so you just have to override that function.

Your code should be:

```
class EventUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin,UpdateView):

    template_name = 'update.html'
    form_class = EventForm
    success_url = '../list'
    queryset = Event.objects.all()    

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        message = "Record has been updated <a href='unupdate?recordtobeunupdated="
        message += str(self.kwargs.get("pk"))
        message += "'>Undo</a>"
        return (mark_safe(message))
```

Let me give you an advice, never treat python libraries / frameworks as a black box entity, just enter them and explore how they work, it will make your programming life lot easier.

Good luck, keep the hard work!

Comment: Thanks, Hagyn. This worked, and I understand it. I removed the unnecessary get_object, as Daniel pointed out, and I edited your last line of code to be message rather than undo_message.

Comment: Glad that it worked! I think you can also remove the form_valid method, you are just calling super.

Comment: Okay I removed form_valid. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you can use django built in messages:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.add_message(
            self.request, 
            messages.SUCCESS, 
            """
            Record has been updated <a href="unupdate?recordtobeunupdated={}">Undo</a>""".format(
                kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']}
             """"
        )

        return super(UserUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

with kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']} you will get the id.

After, you can catch the message in your template:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for msg in messages %}
      <div class="alert
      alert-{% if msg.level_tag == 'debug' %}rose{% endif %}
      {% if msg.level_tag == 'info' %}info{% endif %}
      {% if msg.level_tag == 'success' %}success{% endif %}
      {% if msg.level_tag == 'warning' %}warning{% endif %}
      {% if msg.level_tag == 'error' %}danger{% endif %} alert-with-icon" data-notify="container">
        <i class="material-icons" data-notify="icon">
          {% if msg.level_tag == 'debug' %}code{% endif %}
          {% if msg.level_tag == 'info' %}info{% endif %}
          {% if msg.level_tag == 'success' %}done_all{% endif %}
          {% if msg.level_tag == 'warning' %}warning{% endif %}
          {% if msg.level_tag == 'error' %}error{% endif %}
        </i>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </button>
        <span data-notify="message">
          {% autoescape off %}
            {{ msg.message }}
          {% endautoescape %}
        </span>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

This code above catch every message (assuming you are using a general layout) and render the message as a notification using bootstrap.

more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/)

Answer (score 0):

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin , CreateView):
        model =  Post
        template_name = 'blog/post_create.html'
        fields = ['title', 'content' ]
        success_url = '/'
    
        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.author = self.request.user
            return super().form_valid(form )
    
        def my_fun(self, messages,request):
            messages = messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created, Now you able to login.')
            return super().my_fun( messages )



<div class="container">
    {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message }}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).